# Combine nested arrays into one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

Let's say I have an array of objects that look similar to this:

```
[
   {
     id: ...,
     name: "...",
     users: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    ...
]
```

Is there a way that I can easily merge the .users array of each object into one array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pluck 'n' flatten will do what you want:

```
var result = _.flatten(_.pluck(data, 'users'));
```

**Edit**

As Richard points out, pluck was removed from lodash in version 4.0.0 but still remains in the current version of underscore at time of writing (1.8.3).

Replacing pluck with map works for both lodash and underscore:

```
var result = _.flatten(_.map(data, 'users'));
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution.

Comment: This is now var result = _.flatten(_.map(data, 'users')); 
Since pluck is deprecated and removed.

Comment: Thanks @RichardLindhout ! Have edited the answer to reflect the change.

Comment: And of course, _.union(...) to just include all unique IDs.

Answer (score 2):

Using lodash:

```js
var objects = [
   {
     id: "...",
     name: "...",
     users: [1, 2, 3]
    },
   {
     id: "...",
     name: "...",
     users: [4, 5, 6]
    },
    //...
];
var allUsers = _.flatMap(objects, function(o){return o.users;});

console.log(allUsers);
// allUsers: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not know lodash or underscore, but you can use the native [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) methods of Array (underscore may have equivalent methods, and polyfills for older browsers)

```
var data = [{
     id: ...,
     name: "...",
     users: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    ...
];
var allUsers = [];
data.forEach(function(obj){
   allUsers = allUsers.concat(obj.users);
});

console.log(allUsers);
```

Demo

```js
var data = [{
     id: 1,
     name: "...",
     users: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
     id: 2,
     name: "....",
     users: [4, 5, 6]
    },
    {
     id: 3,
     name: "...",
     users: [7, 8, 9]
    },            
];
var allUsers = [];
data.forEach(function(obj){
   allUsers = allUsers.concat(obj.users);
});

document.querySelector("#log").innerHTML = allUsers.join(",");
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will loop through the original array and return a new array that only contains the values of the `users` arrays. I'm using `Array.prototype.reduce` to keep everything contained but you could technically just do it with a `for` loop too.

```
var data = [{id: 1, name: "A", users: [1, 2, 3]},
            {id: 2, name: "B", users: [4, 5, 6]},
            {id: 3, name: "C", users: [7, 8, 9]}];
var allUsers = data.reduce(function (result, current) {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(result, current.users);
    return result;
}, []);
```

The reason I use `Array.prototype.push` is so that I'm modifying an existing array instead of creating multiple copies (by using something like `Array.prototype.concat`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array.prototype.push` method:

```
var res = [];
for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
   res.push.apply(res, o[i].users);
}
```

If the array should contain unique elements:

```
res = res.filter(function(val, i, arr) { 
    return arr.indexOf(val) === i;
});
```

Comment: `res.push(o[i].users);`

Comment: @self That creates an array of arrays.

Comment: It would result in duplicate users though.

Comment: `a.push.apply(a, b)` is like `a = a.concat(b)`

Comment: just tested it. you're right. strange though. this seems like a hack

Comment: @self The above snippet uses `Function.prototype.apply` method.The way `apply` works can be confusing but it's not  hackish.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [
   {
     id: 1,
     name: "...",
     users: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    ...
];
var res = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].users.forEach(function(val) { res.push(val); }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the most effecient, but it will accomplish what your after.

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TylersDesk/3x1w8y95/

```
var objects = [
    {
        time: 1234,
        users: ["Joe", "Bob", "Blake"]
    },
    {
        time: 1234,
        users: ["Annie", "Gale"]
    }
]

var allUsers = []

for (i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
    for (key in objects[i]) {
        if (key === "users") {
            console.log('found users');
            console.log(objects[i][key]);

            for (g=0; g<objects[i][key].length; g++) {
                console.log(objects[i][key][g]);

                //Add to array
                allUsers.push(objects[i][key][g]);          
            }
        }
    }
}

//Output all users
console.log(allUsers);
```